# How to clear UIButton background image State?

Tags: ios, ios4, uiimage

```
-(void) btnAction:(id) sender {

    NSString *str =((UIButton*)sender).titleLabel.text;

    NSLog(@"%@",str);
    NSLog(@"%@",[dictionary objectForKey:@"option3"]);

    correctAns=[dictionary objectForKey:@"answer"];

        if(str==[dictionary objectForKey:@"option1"])
{

    selectedAns=@"1";

    if ([selectedAns compare:correctAns]==NSOrderedSame) 
    {
     NSLog(@"this is correct");
    [cell.ansBtn1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option_green.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

     countCorrect++;
     cell.lblRating.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", countCorrect];

    }

    else 
    {

        [cell.ansBtn1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option_red.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        cell.lblRating.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", countCorrect];

    }

}
}
```

in Initialization of tableView

```
        - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"BeginingCell";

    cell=(BeginingCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray *topLevelObjects=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BeginingCell" owner:self options:nil ];

        for(id CurrentObject in topLevelObjects)
        {
            if ([CurrentObject isKindOfClass:[BeginingCell class]]) {

                cell=(BeginingCell *) CurrentObject;
                cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


                break;
            }
        }

    }


    if(indexPath.row==0)
    {


       imageURL=[dictionary objectForKey:@"questionImage"];
     //  imageName=[dictionary objectForKey:@"questionImage"];
     // imageURL=@"http://localhost:85/2/";
     // imageURL=[imageURL stringByAppendingString:imageName];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imageURL];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url];
        UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc]  initWithData:data];



        cell.lblScoreCurrent.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", reloader];

        cell.lblScore.text=@"/30";
        cell.myImageView.image = img;
        cell.SectionTitle.text=[dictionary objectForKey:@"question"];




        [cell.ansBtn1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.ansBtn1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option_green.png"] forState: UIControlStateSelected];
        [cell.ansBtn1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option_red.png"] forState: UIControlStateSelected];
}
```

### With changes with your code:

This time it's not even changing the background image from option.jpg to green/red.It's always option.jpg in all click.

****And with my code...i didn't get any error...
****I tested with break point it's going through all the statement properly...even the change of image..but i can't see any backgroud image change.Tell me what is next...

```
  -(void) btnAction:(id) sender {

    NSString *str =((UIButton*)sender).titleLabel.text;

NSLog(@"%@",str);
NSLog(@"%@",[dictionary objectForKey:@"option3"]);

correctAns=[dictionary objectForKey:@"answer"];

if([str isEqualToString:([dictionary objectForKey:@"option1"])])

{

    selectedAns=@"1";

    if ([selectedAns isEqualToString:correctAns]) 
    {
     NSLog(@"this is correct");
     [((UIButton*)sender) setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option_green.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

     countCorrect++;
     cell.lblRating.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", countCorrect];

    }

    else 
    {

        [((UIButton*)sender) setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option_green.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        cell.lblRating.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", countCorrect];

    }

}
```

All the logic are ok..even i am calculating the score..i tested it...just this image issue is not working....please show me a way.....i am totally new in iphone....learning it..so please give me proper instruction if anything is wrong or bad practice...

### After using your code :

Code for the button aciton :

```
    -(void) btnAction:(id) sender {

((UIButton *)sender).selected=FALSE;
NSString *str =((UIButton*)sender).titleLabel.text;
correctAns=[dictionary objectForKey:@"answer"];

if([str isEqualToString:([dictionary objectForKey:@"option1"])])

{

    selectedAns=@"1";
    NSLog(@"Selected Ans = %@",selectedAns);
    NSLog(@"Correct = %@",correctAns);


    if ([selectedAns isEqualToString:correctAns]) 
    {
     NSLog(@"this is correct");

     [((UIButton*)sender) setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option_green.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    //  sleep(3);

     countCorrect++;
     cell.lblRating.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", countCorrect];

    }

    else 
    {

        [((UIButton*)sender) setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option_red.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];



        cell.lblRating.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", countCorrect];

    }

    ((UIButton*)sender).selected = true;

}
```

code in the tableView Indexpath :

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"BeginingCell";

cell=(BeginingCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


if (cell == nil) {

    NSArray *topLevelObjects=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BeginingCell" owner:self options:nil ];

    for(id CurrentObject in topLevelObjects)
    {
        if ([CurrentObject isKindOfClass:[BeginingCell class]]) {

            cell=(BeginingCell *) CurrentObject;
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


            break;
        }
    }

}


if(indexPath.row==0)
{


   imageURL=[dictionary objectForKey:@"questionImage"];
 //  imageName=[dictionary objectForKey:@"questionImage"];
 // imageURL=@"http://localhost:85/2/";
 // imageURL=[imageURL stringByAppendingString:imageName];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imageURL];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url];
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc]  initWithData:data];



    cell.lblScoreCurrent.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", reloader];

    cell.lblScore.text=@"/30";
    cell.myImageView.image = img;
    cell.SectionTitle.text=[dictionary objectForKey:@"question"];


    [cell.ansBtn1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.ansBtn2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.ansBtn3 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.ansBtn4 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];

    cell.ansBtn1.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    cell.ansBtn2.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    cell.ansBtn3.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    cell.ansBtn4.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;



    cell.ansBtn1.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    cell.ansBtn2.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    cell.ansBtn3.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    cell.ansBtn4.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;


    [cell.ansBtn1 setTitle:[dictionary objectForKey:@"option1"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.ansBtn2 setTitle:[dictionary objectForKey:@"option2"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.ansBtn3 setTitle:[dictionary objectForKey:@"option3"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.ansBtn4 setTitle:[dictionary objectForKey:@"option4"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    [cell.ansBtn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(btnAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.ansBtn2 addTarget:self action:@selector(btnAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.ansBtn3 addTarget:self action:@selector(btnAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.ansBtn4 addTarget:self action:@selector(btnAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [cell.ansBtn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(btnActionUp:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    //cell.ansBtn1.showsTouchWhenHighlighted=TRUE;
    cell.ansBtn2.showsTouchWhenHighlighted=TRUE;
    cell.ansBtn3.showsTouchWhenHighlighted=TRUE;
    cell.ansBtn4.showsTouchWhenHighlighted=TRUE;



}


return cell;
```

}

Comment: here is the updated code as your instruction.I debuged it.But there is no problem.I am getting the reg/green image in the next page.Your got the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still dont fully understood your question..If you want one normal image for button , and another when user touches the button, you can give them directly when you create the button itself..No need to change the image when button click..

```
[cell.ansBtn1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[cell.ansBtn1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option_green.png"] forState: UIControlStateHighlighted];
[cell.ansBtn2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[cell.ansBtn2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option_green.png"] forState: UIControlStateHighlighted];
[cell.ansBtn3 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[cell.ansBtn3 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option_green.png"] forState: UIControlStateHighlighted];
[cell.ansBtn4 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[cell.ansBtn4 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option_green.png"] forState: UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Since you have used highlighted state of the button, I presume you want green image only when users hand is on the button (ie change to normal image when user releases the key..).In that case above code will work..

But if you want button image to remain green even after user releases then you should use selected (UIControlStateSelected) property of UIButton..

**Edit:After seeing the comment..**

In that case, when button alloc and init only give normal state image..

```
[cell.ansBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option.png" forState:UIControlStateNormal]];
```

and on button click.

```
-(void)optionButtonClicked:(UIButton*)sender{
   if(correct){
     // green image..
     [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option_green.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
   }else{//red image
     [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option_red.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
   }
   sender.selected = true;
}
```

**Second Edit: After seeing the edited question**

First thing first, Never compare between two strings like this..

```
 if(str==[dictionary objectForKey:@"option1"])
```

Instead compare using compare() function or isEqualToString() function..

Second thing, You are using "**cell**" in the btnAction function. I cant believe it is not showing "**cell is undeclared**" error in compile time. 
Third, correct above two errors.
Fourth,After correcting the error try to debug your code using breakpoints. Have you tried that already? Put a breakpoint in the btnAction function and see if it is executing the way you want..Then update this question with your observations..At the moment, there are so much errors in your code so that I cant tell which one is causing what..To me this code shouldnt get compiled at all..

**Third Edit:Just an afterthought**
try this ..

```
-(void) btnAction:(id) sender {
   ((UIButton*)sender).selected = FALSE; 
    NSString *str =((UIButton*)sender).titleLabel.text;
    NSLog(@"%@",str);
    NSLog(@"%@",[dictionary objectForKey:@"option3"]);
    correctAns=[dictionary objectForKey:@"answer"];
    if([str isEqualToString:([dictionary objectForKey:@"option1"])]){
       selectedAns=@"1";
       If ([selectedAns compare:correctAns]==NSOrderedSame) {
          NSLog(@"this is correct");
          [((UIButton*)sender) setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option_green.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
          countCorrect++;
        //  cell.lblRating.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", countCorrect]; 

        }else {
           [((UIButton*)sender) setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option_red.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
           cell.lblRating.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", countCorrect];
         }
         ((UIButton*)sender).selected = true;
    }
}
```

**Fourth EDIT : one more afterthought**

```
-(void) btnAction:(id) sender {
    NSString *str =((UIButton*)sender).titleLabel.text;
    NSLog(@"%@",str);
    NSLog(@"%@",[dictionary objectForKey:@"option3"]);
    correctAns=[dictionary objectForKey:@"answer"];
    if([str isEqualToString:([dictionary objectForKey:@"option1"])]){
       selectedAns=@"1";
       If ([selectedAns compare:correctAns]==NSOrderedSame) {
          NSLog(@"this is correct");
          [((UIButton*)sender) setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option_green.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
          countCorrect++;
        //  cell.lblRating.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", countCorrect]; 

        }else {
           [((UIButton*)sender) setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option_red.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
           cell.lblRating.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", countCorrect];
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: actually i have 3 background images...option.png(normal),option_green.png(correct),option_red.png(incorrect)...it's like a quiz application.If i click on the correct ans button will be green image on highlight.and if wrong button will be reg image highlighted.you got the idea?or i should upload more code?

Comment: please take a look at the updated code...i used your logic...see the tableView Code for the bakground initialization.And button action for the change....problem is in the first click it's not changing...in the second click it's changing to green/red as it was for first click...as a result i am getting change for previous click in the current click....wot i am doing wrong here?

Comment: when you edit your question never delete your original question..Just append your new edit to the original question

Comment: please take a look now...and tell me should i go back to the original question?i mean if you need..or leave it for now...tell me what should i do now..it's not changing as the code...

Comment: ((UIButton*)sender).selected = true; this line you forgot in your edited question..have you forgot it when debugged it?

Comment: i used it...but..in this case..it's keeping the change selected with the next data...i don't want it..i want to show the change and when reloads new data make it clear with normal state(i mean the option.png image)

Comment: Selected state of button will not change automatically..Next time you have to reset

Comment: how can i reset it?it supposed to reset with the next table load function...isn't it?

Comment: just set ((UIButton*)sender).selected = FALSE;

Comment: where should i make it false?just after making it true?

Comment: try it in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: make sure it is executing every time cell is reloading by putting a breakpoint there...I am going for the day..Hope you will correct it yourself...

Comment: man..you are still having problem..please edit your question with code of what you have now..hold on..what is ur status now?

Comment: i am setting green/red image in my condition.but i am getting the effect on next click...that's the problem.I can't find out the way to show the change of image in the current click aciton.

Comment: sorry for the delay, Sohel14 as a final try can you replace every setBackgroundImage with setImage?

Comment: setImage?or setBackgroundImage?

Comment: you already tried setBackgroundImage right? now try setImage.

Comment: Also can you post your latest btnAction function

Comment: no luck with that..it's acting same...actually we need to set the image...make some delay and set free the with the white image...but i dont know how to do this..i tried adding delay....can we change it using a thread..is there any problem with using thread?

Comment: I cant believe , change a button image is not updating right away...Many times I have done that in the past..

Comment: sorry..I didnt get you..when btn clicked, change the image to green and red, wait for some time and then change image again to normal image..right?

Comment: yes...in all our previous try it was saving the state and showing in our next data load...you got me?

Comment: oops..now last try call [((UIButton*)sender) setNeedsDisplay]; just after setting ((UIButton*)sender).selected = TRUE;..Not a good thing..but a try

Comment: it's all the same for the setImage.What we need to do is setting and showing and clearing it in a click..now give me idea how can i do this?

Comment: trying friend..I still not getting what is your problem..I have changed button image many times and normally it is very easy..but here..